# Wordpress image upload

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, image-uploading

So i was working on an image upload from the front end. I have a custom post type to which i want to set the uploaded images as featured images for a custom post.
I have a multisite, so from what i have researched, wordpress has a separate uploads folder for each site.

My code is as follows:

```
 // Image Upload
        $path = 'images/tmp';

        $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg", "JPG", "PNG", "GIF");
        $name = $_FILES['struct-thumbnail']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['struct-thumbnail']['size'];



        if(strlen($name)) {
            list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
            if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
                if($size<(2048*2048)) { // Image size max 2 MB
                    $actual_image_name = 'structure' .'_'.$new_id .'.'.$ext;
                    $filePath = $path .'/'.$actual_image_name;
                    $tmp = $_FILES['struct-thumbnail']['tmp_name'];

                    $upload = wp_upload_bits($name, null, file_get_contents($tmp));

                    var_dump($upload);

                    // Get the path to the upload directory.
                    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

                    var_dump($wp_upload_dir);

                    if( !$upload['error'] ) {
                        $width = getWidth($filePath);
                        $height = getHeight($filePath);
                        //Scale the image if it is greater than the width set above
                        if ($width > $max_width){
                            $scale = $max_width/$width;
                            $uploaded = resizeImage($filePath,$width,$height,$scale);
                        }else{
                            $scale = 1;
                            $uploaded = resizeImage($filePath,$width,$height,$scale);
                        }

                        $filename = $upload['file'];
                        $attachment = array(
                          'post_mime_type' => $upload['type'],
                          'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
                          'post_content' => '',
                          'post_status' => 'inherit',
                          'guid' => $upload['url']
                        );
                        $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload['url'] );

                        var_dump($attachment_id);

                        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                        $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
                        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );

                        set_post_thumbnail( $new_id, $attachment_id );

                        $img_status = $attachment_id;
                    } else {
                        $img_status = $upload['error'];
                    }
                } else {
                    $img_status = __("Image file size max 1 MB", "skapnet"); 
                }
            } else {
                $img_status = __("Invalid file format.", "skapnet"); 
            }
        }
```

So $upload returns an array with url 
http://skapne-2178.rask17.raskesider.no/tegneprogrammet/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2017/12/example5-large.png

My dumps from above code returns: http://puu.sh/yJuyC/2a0dd0b522.png

BUT if i want to display this in the front end and i use the get_the_post_thumbnail_url() function, it returns the following url 
http://skapne-2178.rask17.raskesider.no/tegneprogrammet/skapnett-slependen/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/sites/9/2017/12/example5-large.png

As u can see the '/sites/9/' is repeated twice. Which is incorrect..So i check the backend in media to see the url, and it's the same. Even though the guid is being set to the right url of $upload['url'] which returns it correctly. Why is this happening??

Comment: seems your problem is `guid` which is setting up by `$upload['url']`, try debug  this variable. let wordpress handle the `guid` see what happens.

Comment: the variable $upload['url'] is correct. It returns ["url"]=>
  string(111) "http://skapne-2178.rask17.raskesider.no/tegneprogrammet/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2017/12/example6-large-1.png"